# What is this for loop stacking called?

Tags: c++

```
for (pos.X = mesh_position.X - 1; pos.X <= mesh_position.X + mesh_grid.cell_size; pos.X++)
for (pos.Z = mesh_position.Z - 1; pos.Z <= mesh_position.Z + mesh_grid.cell_size; pos.Z++)
for (pos.Y = mesh_position.Y - 1; pos.Y <= mesh_position.Y + mesh_grid.cell_size; pos.Y++) {
    MapBlock *block = map->getBlockNoCreateNoEx(pos);
    map_blocks.push_back(block);
    if (block)
        block->refGrab();
}
```

Ive never seen this syntax before and its not searchable. Can someone explain what it does?

Comment: what specifically? Its 3 nested loops with bad intendation

Comment: Put in the optional braces and you'll see it's nothing special.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number the bad indentation is a blessing in this case, you're less likely to add a statement and think it's part of the loop.

Comment: Remove the unnecessary code -- all it does is clutter what is happening.  `for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)` `for(int j = 0; j < 10; ++j)` `for (int k = 0; k < 10; ++k) { }`.  Is that more understandable?

Comment: @MarkRansom depends on style and conventions. When I see the first line but not the whole line, I expect it to be a `for` loop with the body in the same line. And because for nested loops intendation is different, I would look no further, add a statement, and see it fail

Comment: You can put statements in a for loop.  A for loop is a statement.

Comment: The most common name is _"curly wurly"_ and it's majorily advised to avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is this for loop stacking called?

There is no name for the concept of writing one line after another with poor indentation.

Allow me to add clarifying braces and whitespace to your code.

```
for (pos.X = mesh_position.X - 1; pos.X <= mesh_position.X + mesh_grid.cell_size; pos.X++)
{
    for (pos.Z = mesh_position.Z - 1; pos.Z <= mesh_position.Z + mesh_grid.cell_size; pos.Z++)
    {
        for (pos.Y = mesh_position.Y - 1; pos.Y <= mesh_position.Y + mesh_grid.cell_size; pos.Y++)
        {
            MapBlock *block = map->getBlockNoCreateNoEx(pos);
            map_blocks.push_back(block);
            if (block)
                block->refGrab();
        }
    }
}
```